# Закрытые вкладки по умолчанию ui kit accordion

Tags: css, uikit

По умолчанию в uikit accordion первая вкладка всегда открыта. Есть такой код

```html
<div  class="uk-accordion"  data-uk-accordion="{collapsible: false;multiple:false; }" >

<h2 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 1</h2>
<div  class="uk-accordion-content">
<p>Описание 1</p> 
</div> 

<h2 class="uk-accordion-title">Item 2</h2>
<div  class="uk-accordion-content">
<p>Описание 2</p> 
</div> 

</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы по умолчанию все вкладки были сразу закрыты, а открывались только по нажатию

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `showfirst`.

```
data-uk-accordion="{collapsible: false;multiple:false; showfirst: false;}"
```